# How to make theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, themes, expandablelistview

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoyOa.jpg)

I have a task to create this theme. Can anyone help me on how to create this type of theme. I have no idea about this, so I am not giving my code here.

Comment: Looks like you can use the stepper widget. Check this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html and this: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/stepper-widget-in-flutter-37ce5b45575b

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily with the use of this library im_stepper: ^0.1.3